# Fully qualified interface name

Tags: php

Is there a way to get fully qualified interface name similar to `MyClass::class`?

For example:

```
namespace Example\Tests;

use Example\Interfaces\InputInterface;
...

class CommandTest ...
...
public function createInputMock()
{
    // I want to replace next string with something similar to MyClass::class
    $this->getMockBuilder('Example\Interfaces\InputInterface')
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: `InputInterface::class` isn't good?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find this in the php documentation related to interfaces so I thought it works only with class names. You could post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) name resolution can work with *any* imported namespaces: classes, interfaces, functions, ...

```
namespace A\B\C {
    interface Interface_Bar {}
    function Function_Foo() {}
    function Function_Foo_Bar() {}
    const Const_BARFOO = 123;
}

namespace {
    use A\B\C\Interface_Bar;
    use A\B\C;
    use Undefined\Classes\UndefinedClass;
    use function A\B\C\Function_Foo_Bar;
    use const A\B\C\Const_BARFOO;

    echo Interface_Bar::class, "\n"; // print A\B\C\Interface_Bar
    echo C\Function_Foo::class, "\n"; // print A\B\C\Function_Foo
    echo C\Const_BARFOO::class, "\n"; // print A\B\C\Const_BARFOO
    echo UndefinedClass::class, "\n"; // print Undefined\Classes\UndefinedClass

    echo Function_Foo_Bar::class, "\n"; // print Function_Foo_Bar <- warning
    echo Const_BARFOO::class, "\n"; // print Const_BARFOO <- warning
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you can't move to PHP 5.5 with `::class` notation, so you want to have something similar in your 5.4 or earlier vesrion.

So the short answer is — no, there is no way.

The lack of this functionality in the previous versions of PHP is what made core developers to add `::class` to PHP 5.5.

You can make a weird dirty hack if it's a class name: using [get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) on new instance, but don't do it.